# split a list with title value: pythonic way

Tags: python

I have a text, like this:

```
[1]
aaa
bbb
[2]
ccc
ddd
```

What I want:

```
{ 'title1': [ 'aaa', 'bbb' ],
  'title2': [ 'ccc', 'ddd' ] }
```

I can split this text with `\n` and use `for` and some `if` statements to do this, but no 'pythonic', elegance way for this? kind of key (`[1], [2]`) is limited.

**Edit**: My attempt is here, and so hard-coded:

```
item = string.split('\n')
result = {}

for i in item:
    # get title item
    if i[0] == '[':
        name = re.sub(r'(\[|\])', '', item[i])
        continue
    # ...and put into result dict
    if name == '1':
        if not 'breakfast' in result:
            result['breakfast'] = []
        result['breakfast'].push(value)
    if name == '2':
        if not 'lunch' in result:
            result['lunch'] = []
        result['lunch'].push(value)
    if name == '3':
        if not 'dinner' in result:
            result['dinner'] = []
        result['dinner'].push(value)
```

Comment: Also, lists can't be keys, they'll have to be tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
current_key = "ERROR - MISSING TITLE"
with open('youfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        item = line.strip()
        if item.strip('[]') != item:
            current_key = item.strip('[]')
        else:
            result[current_key].append(item)
```

If you don't want to use a `defaultdict` you can do `result = {}` and change `result[current_key].append(item)` to `result.setdefault(current_key, []).append(item)`.

Comment: Thank you for simple answer `collections` module, it wasn't in my googling scope :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use groupby to group the lines not starting with a `[` with an OrderedDict to keep the order the data appeared in your file:

```
from itertools import groupby, imap
from collections import OrderedDict
with open("in.txt") as f:
    grouped = groupby(imap(str.rstrip, f), lambda x: x[0] == "[")
    od = OrderedDict(("title{}".format(next(v).strip("[]")), list(next(grouped)[1]))
                     for k, v in grouped)
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('title1', ['aaa', 'bbb']), ('title2', ['ccc', 'ddd'])])
```

If the numbers always start at one just use enumerate with a start index of 1:

```
od = OrderedDict(("title{}".format(ind), list(next(grouped)[1]))
                 for ind, (k, v) in enumerate(grouped, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are attempting to parse a configuration file, the python [configparser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) can help so that you don't need to re-invent the wheels. Reference the example in the end of the page.

```
    >>> import ConfigParser
    >>> import io
    >>>
    >>> sample_config = """
    ... [1]
    ... aaa
    ... bbb
    ... [2]
    ... ccc
    ... ddd
    ... """
    >>> config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
    >>> config.readfp(io.BytesIO(sample_config))
    >>> config.sections()
    ['1', '2']
    >>> config.items("1")
    [('aaa', None), ('bbb', None)]
    >>> config.items("2")
    [('ccc', None), ('ddd', None)]
```